# Where to host a Flask + SQLite3?

Tags: sqlite, flask

I am trying to host my website to run 4 Scrapy spiders for free, but cannot find a host that supports Python and uses SQLite3. I looked at Heroku, but using PostgreSQL confuses me. Where can I find a host?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where to host a Flask + SQLite3 web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660277/where-to-host-a-flask-sqlite3-web-app)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a sqlite database connection for a flask app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58876713/creating-a-sqlite-database-connection-for-a-flask-app)